# Pausing a script running in terminal screen?

Tags: shell

I'm running a script inside of a terminal screen in a remote machine I ssh'ed in, so I can exit and enter terminal any time. I had thought that to pause the script, I'd just have to either send a ^Z command to the screen, or go into the screen and hit ^Z (or ^A^Z). But neither of them worked. All it did was that it paused the `screen -r` command I used to enter the screen.

I'm running on a device incapable of installing any dependencies such as reptyr, gcc, or apt-get. That's why I'm resorting to using screens to run/pause my script.

Comment: As this question doesn't seem to be about programming, the right place to ask would be at [https://unix.stackexchange.com/](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).